# Change border color of a UITableViewCell on selection

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitableview

I am using a custom table view cell for my tableview. For setting the border, I have put a view on the custom cell and I am changing its border properties.

```
self.borderView.layer.borderColor = VIEW_BORDER_COLOR;
```

I want to highlight the selected cell by changing it's border color. I tried to change it in didselectrowforindexpath,

```
cell.borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
```

but as the cells are reused it changes on scrolling.

Comment: you are doing multiple selection or single selection...

Comment: [cell setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES]; try this one...

Answer (score 36):

Using:

> **Swift 2** :

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
```

> **Swift 3**

```
cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use 
**Objective-C**

```
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor]; 
[cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

**Swift 5**

```
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Will have to mark/un-mark(assuming u need only one selected at a time) the border color again and again like-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row==self.selectedRow){
cell.borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
}else {
cell.borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
}
}
```

Just save/cache the selected index like-

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//Unselected the prevoius selected Cell
            YourCellClass *aPreviousSelectedCell=  (YourCellClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedRow inSection:0]];
            aPreviousSelectedCell.borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

//Selected the new one-    
           YourCellClass *aSelectedCell = (YourCellClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    aSelectedCell.borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor; 

            self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
        }
```

Comment: Glad if it worked..may consider accepting the correct answer:)

Comment: borderView is not a valid property for UITableViewCell